# Spring '14 Force.com and Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open

Tags: discussion

Not really a question, but wanted to let everyone know the nominations for [Force.com MVP](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2014/04/spring-14-force-com-mvp-nominations-are-open-2.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20SforceBlog%20%28Force.com%20Blog%29) and [Salesforce MVP](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/04/vote-now-spring-14-salesforce-mvp-nominations-are-open.html) are open. Nominate people who have made a difference on the site.

Comment: thanks Daniel, you're on my list!

Comment: Shame for the ones who don't have blogs :)

Comment: True, they are looking for contributions across multiple channels including Stack Exchange, blogs, success community, open source projects, etc.

Comment: Will they award an anonymous MVP?  @user320 for sure, if so!!!

Comment: You can follow the mystery that is @user320 on Twitter too: https://twitter.com/user_320.

Comment: All roads leads to LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/mjbingham aka bruce wayne if someone's trying to nominate him :)

Comment: for MVP i would say @Keith C

Answer (score 9):

There's quite a few people on this site I'll be putting forward, some really awesome people on here who definitely deserve recognition for that they do. That said, Salesforce do look for engagement on multiple channels so do as much as you can! :)

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out elsewhere, engagement in a single channel, however deep, is unlikely to be considered enough to make it as an MVP.  That said, the decisions are taken by Salesforce and the criteria are not public, so those of us in the program don't know exactly how things work, but we do know what got us and others there.

For anyone who is targeting MVP status and would like some assistance or advice around engaging with a wider audience, we have an MVP mentorship team tasked with providing exactly that.  I'm on this team so if it is something you are serious about, reach out to me and we'll see about finding you someone in your timezone to help you.